# neo4j connecting via groovy

Tags: groovy, ssh, neo4j

Trying to connect to my Neo4j instance on a server I ssh into (linux server).  I have added all my jar files and have this code

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
Node firstNode;
Node secondNode;
Relationship relationship;
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
```

However, because the instance of the database is not on the same machine I am running on, I don't know what to replace `DB_PATH` with.
My Database webadmin is running at 10.7.19.73:7474/webadmin/ and I am sshing into `10.9.19.73`

The path to my neo4j folder is `/tmp/neo4j/`  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to a remote Neo4j instance, you need to use https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding.

When using groovy, I strongly recommend using `@Grab` annotation, to manage dependencies and create a self-contained script, see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape

As an example:

```
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-rest-graphdb", version="1.9.M04")
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase

def db = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
def node = db.getNodeById(0)
println node
db.shutdown()
```